# Best Method for Sorting and Displaying Unique Values in a Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like opinions on the best method for sorting and displaying unique values from a column in a Workbook.  The idea is to place all the values within a cell in a tracker spreadsheet.  I can create the scripting dictionary for unique values, and print them in the Immediate Window, but sorting the results seems complicated.  Here's what I have:

```
Sub HostIP()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String
Dim key As Variant

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
WB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

If InStr(WB, "swpaViolRPT") > 0 Then
    
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("J4:J" & LastRow)   'Assembling the Scripting Dictionary
    tmp = UCase(Trim(c.Value))
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    'Debug.Print c, d(c)
Next c
End If

For Each key In d.keys
    Debug.Print key
Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a list of IP addresses ? If so do they need to be sorted by each octet ? How many approx hundreds or thousands ?

Comment: The method of sorting isn't all that important, just that it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the macro recorder comes in handy. Start the recorder, select the range, sort, remove duplicates, stop the recorder, edit the macro, and done.

Comment: I hadn't had too much luck with this method before, but this DOES give me a few clues.  Thanks!